# Rails & FontAwesome - link inside span doesn't work

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I've got a simple rails form, laid out with haml and want to use fontAwesome icons for the actions, instead of "Show, Edit...". So I created this code to put the link inside a fontAwesome'd span:

```
%td{:width => "7%"}
  %span{:class => "fa fa-id-card-o"}= link_to '', log
  %span{:class => "fa fa-pencil-square-o"}= link_to "", edit_log_path(log)
  %span{:class => "fa fa-trash"}= link_to '', log, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

It generates this html:

```
<td width="7%">
  <span class="fa fa-id-card-o"><a href="/logs/46"></a></span>
  <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"><a href="/logs/46/edit"></a></span>
  <span class="fa fa-trash"><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logs/46"></a></span>
</td>
```

which looks to me as if it should work since the `<a>` is inside the `<span>`.

However, none of the icons are clickable.

The display looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Icons should be inside the anchors, otherwise anchors wouldn't have "clickable" content. Did you try "upside-down"; span tags within anchors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon should be inside the `<a>` and `</a>`. Right now it's empty.

In HAML you will have to do something like this:

```
= link_to log, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do
  %span{:class => "fa fa-trash"}
```

It will place span under link and generated html would be something like this  `<a ...> <span/> </a>`